# "Contesting the palm" -- looking for a definition and possible origin of this archaic phrase

Tags: etymology, archaicisms

I recently ran across an odd phrase—"contest the palm"—and after doing some Google searches found it used by a number of individuals in England during the 1800s but I cannot seem to find it defined anywhere. **I am extremely interested in finding its origins if possible.**

Here is the text I ran across first:

> "At the same time were produced, from the same university, the two great poets, Cowley and Milton, of dissimilar genius, of opposite principles; but concurring in the cultivation of Latin poetry, in which the English, till their works and [*Thomas*] May's poem appeared, seemed unable to **contest the palm** with any other of the lettered nations."
>   .          -- [*The Works of Samuel Johnson, LL.D..: Lives of the Poets* (1825)](https://books.google.com/books?id=wEgJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=lives+of+the+poets+contest+the+palm+samuel+johnson&source=bl&ots=GhrnkwZXBw&sig=U2aqBd8XdQj5LMr7ZUHwO-wC-6o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIivfj-PvryAIVSTo-Ch3leAMO#v=snippet&q=%22contest%20the%20palm%22&f=false)

Googling: ["contest the palm" england](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22contest%20the%20palm%22%20england&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Fw0uVpf9HMToUpSrhNgK) provides this example of usage (third result)

> In biography the French are unrivalled, in autobiography the Germans are equally so. In some species of poetry the Germans **contest the palm** with us: in mathematical industry, and historical research, they are greatly our superiors;
>
> *The Rural Life of England*, 1838

A number of similar examples can be found [**here**](http://nyanglish.com/contest-the-palm) (some of the examples can be clicked on to see expanded context) with references to:

> - "contest the palm of original genius"
>     -- *Ben-Hur: A Tale of the Christ* (1880)
> - "contest the palm of temper"
>     -- *The Heir of Redclyffe* (1853)
> - "contest the palm of literary precedence"
>     -- *History of the Reign of Ferdinand and Isabella V3* (1837)

Searches in Google found these other usages:

> - "contest the palm of eloquence"
>     -- [*The Life of Sir Samuel Romilly, V2* (1812)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Nfo2l0fMnb4C&pg=PA283&lpg=PA283&dq=%22contest+the+palm+of%22&source=bl&ots=EcQZbpHMRb&sig=10Ha-SkrzcHdTcoZY2LQTznPH1c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAmoVChMImKrZkePryAIVQ9RjCh1akQB1#v=onepage&q=%22contest%20the%20palm%20of%22&f=false)
> - "contest the palm of rifle shooting"
>     -- [*The People's Press, and Monthly Historical Newspaper, V2* (1848)](https://books.google.com/books?id=iTPmUgAg1EQC&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=%22contest+the+palm+of%22&source=bl&ots=1yZTROfpYJ&sig=XrNlN2IyGh07VTRTivXu4fBkJkY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDsQ6AEwCWoVChMImKrZkePryAIVQ9RjCh1akQB1#v=onepage&q=%22contest%20the%20palm%20of%22&f=false)
> - "contest the palm of beauty"
>     -- [*The Chien D'or: The Golden Dog; a Legend of Quebec* (1877)](https://books.google.com/books?id=CFoqAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA347&lpg=PA347&dq=%22contest+the+palm+of%22&source=bl&ots=Zu13NRdoVl&sig=ENpRxEVfufY8ZkCazPsEnOL00p4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwBGoVChMInbeI9eTryAIVwVc-Ch2LmQk8#v=onepage&q=%22contest%20the%20palm%20of%22&f=false)
> - "contest the palm of science"
>     -- [*The Life of Napoleon Buonaparte, Emperor of the French, V2* (1828)](https://books.google.com/books?id=mN8oAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=%22contest+the+palm+of%22&source=bl&ots=-0GiPogeGT&sig=c2AI_MfO4zNjzpVl3PDDzGGdIl8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwB2oVChMInbeI9eTryAIVwVc-Ch2LmQk8#v=onepage&q=%22contest%20the%20palm%20of%22&f=false)
> - "contest the palm of agreeableness and popularity"
>     -- [*Chamber's Book of Days* (1869)](http://www.thebookofdays.com/months/sept/25.htm)
> - "contest the palm of productive capacity with the slave"
>     -- [*Richmond's Daily Dispatch* (1861)](http://www.civilwar-online.com/2011/03/march-23-1861-daily-dispatch-virginias.html)
> - "contest the palm of might or majesty"
>     -- [*The New York Times* (1883)](http://query.nytimes.com/mem/archive-free/pdf?res=9802E0D6133BE033A25754C0A9669D94629FD7CF)

However, despite these many usages I can find no explicit reference to the term in any dictionary or encyclopedia, no etymology of any kind, and it seems to have [**appeared in print first in 1776**](https://books.google.com/books?id=p8g1AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA505&lpg=RA1-PA505&dq=%22contest+the+palm%22+1776&source=bl&ots=-Us-gAgkVw&sig=29q-nbqBBJRcwfn_YNupWQhuFPo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIqd7a1f3ryAIVTG4-Ch2Ocwu5#v=onepage&q=%22contest%20the%20palm%22%201776&f=false), and remained in widespread usage for more than a century.

I do wonder if this might be a colloquial phrase that was brought over from a non-English usage (perhaps from French, which was the international language at this point in history) but my French is not sufficient to be able to research this.

Still, it would be nice to find out more about the origins of this phrase.

Comment: Please can you give some of the surrounding text and give a link?  This saves us having to repeat the research you have done. Thanks. (Also a selection of links would be good.)

Comment: P.S. This is a normal request on the site, e.g. "...Any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem..." http://english.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error

Comment: Sure. For starters I found that [**this Google search**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22contest+the+palm%22+england&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) worked well to just randomly find various usages. By context the phrase seems to mean "something of high quality". I'll build a short list and post it as soon as possible, trying to get ready for work right now.

Comment: I'm afraid I am going to have to be away from the computer for several hours but in the meantime I found this nice concise [**set of examples**](http://nyanglish.com/contest-the-palm) for your use. If you click on some of the examples they expand to include more surrounding text.

Comment: Including the research means posting it in the actual question, and maybe including a snippet. It may seem nothing, it may seem fussy and persnickety but it does make a huge difference. The question looks more interesting if nothing else!

Comment: You should have heard of the [Palme d'Or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palme_d%27Or).

Comment: @PeterShor immediately, when I saw only the question title,  my first thought was the hand (palm up) gesture one makes when saying "Talk to the hand". (I'm half-kidding here) :)

Comment: I would like to apologize to everyone. I became pretty sick the day I posted this and have really been out of it for the past couple of days. Thank you @Mari-LouA for editing the question in my absence.

Comment: @PeterShor: The Palme d'Or was introduced at the Cannes Film Festival in 1955, quite a bit later than the 19th century usage I am referring to. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I have expanded the question as requested. It fascinates me that such a phrase was used so widely and so long yet is not defined anywhere I can locate.

Comment: It's a bit late though... The request was made on October 26 *before* the post was edited to include a snippet, and the google link, which you posted in the comments. It's also a bit late in the day, seeing as you received one very good detailed  answer. Are you unsatisfied with Josh61's answer?

Comment: Adding the Wikipedia link *King of the Hill* is implying that you understand the meaning of *contest the palm*; you are *now* comparing the two expressions: the older, more historical sounding expression with its modern-day counterpart. Effectively, you are CHANGING the focus of your original question.  This is unfair, and not Kosher on EL&U.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I changed the Q per your "warm recommendation". Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I realize this is late but I did want to create a "quality" question as chaslyfromUK suggested. I have been really ill and focusing on writing up the expanded question was not something I was really capable of before today.

Comment: You could ask a new question, linking it to this "old" one and ask why this expression was adopted by the English between 18-19th century. Whether it had to due with prestige, whether because French used to be  the lingua franca. You could also ask "why" this expression has died out, and what has since replaced it. (Perfect!)  Include the research you have done, the 1776 reference, which is very cool, and which I would delete from here, and you have a very very good second question IMO.

Answer (score 13):

It appears to refer to ***[palm](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/palm)*** meaning:

> - a symbol of triumph or superiority; also :  victory, triumph (M-W)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=contest%20the%20palm&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontest%20the%20palm%3B%2Cc0) shows a number of "contest the palm"  usages especially  in the 19th century. I think is it is an expression which is just to be taken literally.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=palm%20of%20victory&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpalm%20of%20victory%3B%2Cc0) the expression "the palm of victory" was popular during the 19th century.

> - The Lucioda of Mrs. Mountain cannot be surpassed, and Mrs. Bland, in Madge, may be allowed to ***contest the palm of victory*** with Mrs. Martyr, who has deservedly acquired great reputation in that character. The Bravura, by Giordani,  .. [The Monthly Mirror -1802](https://books.google.it/books?id=qgg2AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA132&dq=%22contest%20the%20palm%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMI_djMuPzfyAIVghAsCh2tLQ9M#v=onepage&q=%22contest%20the%20palm%22&f=false)

As for its origin,  a  ***[palm branch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm_branch_(symbol))*** as a symbol of victory dates back to the the earlest civilisations:

> - The palm branch is a symbol of victory, triumph, peace and eternal life originating in the ancient Near East and Mediterranean world. The palm (Phoenix) was sacred in Mesopotamian religions, and in ancient Egypt represented immortality. In Judaism, a closed frond of the date palm is part of the festival of Sukkot.
> - A palm branch was awarded to victorious athletes in ancient Greece, and a palm frond or the tree itself is one of the most common attributes of Victory personified in ancient Rome.

(Wikipedia)

[image]

Comment: -1 for not waiting for the OP to provide the research that they said they would do.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - is my answer wrong or inaccurate? Is it a valid reason to downvote?

Comment: If a question is not properly researched then we are encouraged to vote to close. I prefer to ask the OP to do the research before close-voting.  O.M.Y. was very obliging so it's only polite to wait now.  It is a habit of some people to simply guess before there is enough context. This leads to poor quality answers. Maybe not in this case but let's wait and see.  (Also, when others see a well-researched question, it encourages them to do likewise.)

Comment: P.S. Personally  I think it is a valid reason. It would be interesting to see what others think. Maybe there could be a question on meta about that?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - to me the question was clear, the description given was enough to understand what OP was looking for. Further details may be helpful but not essential. What OP added in the comments just confirms that.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - if you want to make a case of it, do it.

Comment: i don't think this answer deserves a downvote as the phrase "contest the palm" doesn't have multiple meanings that might cause confusion depending on the context. I have seen worse questions than this one and this question is stating at least the OP tried to find a reference.

Comment: @Josh61, Thanks, it's certainly not personal. Maybe I'll put a question on meta. I'd be interested to see other people's opinions on this. My motivation (in this sort of situation) is to get people to ask high quality *questions*.  I'm not criticising your answer.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - the more an answer is researched, the better, but in this case I didn't have to "guess". The question is clear..19th century usage of the expression "contest the palm" is it idiomatic?

Comment: @Josh61, Suppose someone asked, "What does 'incomprehensible' mean and they didn't give any research or explain why it was difficult for them. Would you answer or would you vote to close because they should have used a dictionary? The OP could have looked up the same sources you did. If that still didn't make sense in *their* context *then* they would be justified in asking.  (Note, I have been criticised for jumping in too quickly myself in the past).  P.S. I have removed the down-vote but my point still stands.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - unlike "incomprehensible", "contest the palm" is not an expression that you can find on dictionaries. Its usage appears to be peculiar to the 19th century, an important piece of information OP gave. Asking for its meaning and possible idiomatic usage is just fine to me. You  and other users may have a different opinion, that is just fine and helpful.

Comment: I disagree but we are way into meta now. If I post in meta, can I use this as an example? Note: I am quite aware that I may be in the minority but it would be interesting to find out.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - please do, I have said all I have to say about this issue.

Comment: Okay, it's here. http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/is-it-valid-to-downvote-on-account-of-an-answer-being-too-hasty

Answer (score 3):

[Palm](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/palm) (second entry, meaning 3: see slso 2 and 4); merit or victory.  Another way of saying it would be 'to vie for the gold medal'.